# Erro ao redirecionar usuario para pagina de login com vue 3

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

boa tarde, estou recebendo o seguinte erro ao tentar redirecionar o usuário para a página de login, no vue js 3
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
Essa página verifica se o usuário possui um token para saber se o ele está logado. Se estiver autenticado, apresenta o conteúdo dela normalmente. Caso contrário, deveria redirecionar para a página de login.
Porém, ao tentar redirecionar para o login, o erro da imagem acima é apresentado.

Nunca trabalhei com VueJS e estou com essa dúvida.

Seguem os códigos:

main.js

```html
import { createApp } from "vue";
import App from "./App.vue";
import store from "./store";

import { clickOutsideDirective } from "./directives/outsideClickHandler";
import i18nPlugin from "./plugins/i18n/i18nPlugin";

import Axios from "axios";


import router from "./router";
import routerLogin from "./router/login"
//import routerLogin from "./routerAutenticacao"
//import routerLogin from "./router/login"

//var axiosIntance = Axios.create({ baseURL: "https://localhost:5001/" });
var axiosIntance = Axios.create({
    baseURL: store.getters.baseURL
});
// declare a response interceptor
axiosIntance.interceptors.response.use(
    (response) => {
        return response;
    },
    (error) => {
        if (error && error.response && error.response.status === 401) {
            localStorage.removeItem("user-token");
            window.location.reload();
        }
        return Promise.reject(error);
    }
);
const app = createApp(App);
app.config.globalProperties.$http = axiosIntance;

const token = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user-token"));

if (token) {
    app.config.globalProperties.$http.defaults.headers.common["Authorization"] =
        "bearer " + token.token;
    app.config.devtools = true;
    app.config.globalProperties.$http = axiosIntance;
    app.provide("http", app.config.globalProperties.$http);
    console.log('autorizado');
    app.directive("click-outside", clickOutsideDirective);
    app
        .use(router)
        .use(store)
        .use(i18nPlugin, { locale: "br" })
        .mount("#app");
} else {
    console.log('não autorizado')
    app
        .use(routerLogin)
        .use(store)
        .use(i18nPlugin, { locale: "br" })
        .mount("#app");
    //window.location.href = ('/login.html');
}
```

Index.js

```html
import { RouterView } from "vue-router";
//import Vue from 'vue'
//import Router from 'vue-router'
import { createRouter, createWebHashHistory } from "vue-router";
const Login = () =>
    import ("@/views/login/Login.vue");


const routes = {
    path: "/login",
    name: "Logar",
    component: RouterView,
    children: [{
            path: "",
            name: "Logar",
            component: Login
        },

    ]
};
const routerLogin = createRouter({
    history: createWebHashHistory(),
    routes,
});

export default routerLogin;
```

O erro mais precisamente esta nesse else que leva para o login mas n sei porque
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Prezado Carlos, dê uma olhada nesse tutorial: https://blog.sqreen.com/authentication-best-practices-vue/ (talvez possa te ajudar).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

consegui resolver de forma bem simples até
Fiz o mount no #app e se o usuário não tiver token
eu passo router.push({ name: "Login" })
minha roda de login

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Que legal! Então marque sua própria resposta como correta :-)